# Override a Rails Engine controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

i'm using a Rails engine, but i need to customize some controllers actions.

I actually forked the engine, and implementing those customizations into my own fork, but i was wondering if there is an official way in Rails Engines to override and customize controllers.

Comment: Have a look there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045068/extending-controllers-of-a-rails-3-engine-in-the-main-app

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just define a controller with the same name in your own `app\controllers` folder, and it will be found first.
That way you can easily customize it.

Please note: because it is found first, you replace the entire controller from the engine. This could be exactly what you want. In some cases, you just want to adjust a little, then it is much better to reopen the class, and only redefine what is needed.

Examples to do is can be found here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#overriding-models-and-controllers

Comment: A lot easier than maintaing a custom fork!
Thanks and sorry for the lame question!

Comment: This will override the entire controller, not just one action.

Comment: I didn't claim otherwise. But at least you can customize it. Do you have a better solution?

Comment: There are several, of which this seems to be the preferred method - http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#overriding-models-and-controllers

Comment: Thanks, I adapted my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 15):

The link in the accepted answer does not actually provide an example to overriding a controller. They mention "open classing" the file, but don't explain how exactly to do it. If you open the engine class in your app, you will get a circular dependency error because you are referencing/opening a class that is currently in the process of being defined. Therefore, you need to make sure you load the engine's actual class first.

```
# in my app
# app/controllers/blazer/base_controller.rb
load Blazer::Engine.root.join('app/controllers/blazer/base_controller.rb')
Blazer::BaseController.class_eval do
  filter_access_to :all
end
```

In my case, I'm using the [Blazer](https://github.com/ankane/blazer) gem and adding authentication to it. Since I use declarative authorization, which Blazer does not directly support, I need to open up Blazer's base controller and add my authorization requirement to it.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it gives an example of what the OP was asking for as well uses format the docs in the rails guide suggest.

Comment: Works! Is this the most idiomatically rails way to do this?

Comment: @DavidT I believe so. I see this all over in gems that produce engines.